# Correct syntax for setting destination folder in PHP

Tags: php, upload, directory

I'm trying to adapt an upload script to fit on 000webhost. I keep getting errors about the destination folder not existing. This is what I have:

```
define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','/uploads/');
```

I've also tried

```
/public_html/uploads/
```

and

```
/subdomain/domain/com/uploads/
```

In examples I've seen people were using /www/ but I don't know where that goes.

What is the correct syntax to use in this case?

Comment: It should be "/home/username/public_html/uploads/", that's what 000 uses lol. Your username is the 'axxxxxxx' where xxxx = random numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
define('DESTINATION_FOLDER',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/');
```

Consider using the PHP constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, if platform independence matters to you:

```
define('DESTINATION_FOLDER',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
                            'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

**EDIT**:
Storing uploads under the document root can be a security risk. Unless you want those files to be directly accessible by the web server, you should consider storing them outside of the document root within your webspace. If you created a folder named "uploads" along side your "public_html" folder with your host, you could access it like this:

```
define('DESTINATION_FOLDER',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
                            '..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. // (up one level)
                            'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Or just specify an absolute path (leading with `/`) directly to the folder.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, but please don't actually put user-uploaded files under the doc root!  This is potentially a huge security problem.

Comment: @Brad That really depends on the case, but I agree with you.

Comment: this is not working. still getting the same error. "Destination folder does not exist or no permissions to see it." Permissions are set to 777 for uploads.

Comment: @HiggsBoson Then I suggest you `var_dump(DESTINATION_FOLDER)` and see how it lines up with where you think you created the folder. Also see if `DESTINATION_FOLDER` is getting concatenated with anything else.

Comment: @jimp "Or just specify an absolute path (leading with /) directly to the folder." That's what I was originally trying to do, but I don't know what the absolute path is, where it starts, etc.

Comment: @HiggsBoson `var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);` will likely reveal that.

Comment: @jimp "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/uploads/" is returned when i var_dump. i tried replacing that string with what you gave me but still no luck. i need it to be in the public_html folder, as that is where it is. i'm only uploading images and they need to be recalled by other scripts

Comment: @jimp `var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);` did it. Brilliant, thank you. Now to fix the rest of the bugs..